# How to encode data in hexadecimal?

Tags: php, hex, bin2hex

The code:

```
#0c0f56415445532d413636373231343939
```

Is: `VATES-A66721499` but encoded in hex.

I have made the following attempt:

```
$hex = bin2hex('VATES-A66721499');
echo $hex;
```

output:

```
56415445532d413636373231343939
```

But I need to get this other part:

```
#0c0f
```

I have tried the following but no result: `#0c0f56415445532d413636373231343939`

Comment: `0f` might be the length, and `0c` might be a tag. You need to find out where the encoding comes from or is specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0c` and `0f` are unprintable control characters, and `#` is not part of hexadecimal encoding at all.

You can either:

```php
'#' . bin2hex("\x0c\x0f" . 'VATES-A66721499')
```

Or:

```php
'#0c0f' . bin2hex('VATES-A66721499')
```

Both will give the desired output.